# Finding area under a curve without using trigonometrics

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

[image]

Using the circle equation I derived roots at $(16,8)$ and $(0,0)$.  In an effort to stay true to the question we decided that since the line gets a little blurry with trig and known relationships within shapes we said that just no using $\sin$, $\cos$, $\tan$ was enough for no trig requirement.

Also, I do not speak Chinese so if there is any extra info in there, let me know!

I have had several guys guess that it might not be possible, lets find out!

Comment: Maybe Jack Ma knows the answer? :)

Comment: Please check my solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'll skip the part that you already solved. Let's start from this picture:

[image]

Triangles $\triangle DHF$ and $\triangle EJF$ are obviously similar. It means that:

$$\angle ADF=\angle BEF=\alpha$$

We want to calculate the following areas:

$$P_1=area(sector(DAF))-area(\triangle DAF)=20^2\pi\frac{\alpha}{2\pi}-\frac{20\times 16}{2}=200\alpha-160$$

$$P_2=area(sector(AEF))-area(\triangle AEF)=10^2\pi\frac{\pi-\alpha}{2\pi}-\frac{10\times 8}{2}=50(\pi-\alpha)-40$$

$$P=P_1+P_2$$

$$P=200\alpha-160 + 50(\pi-\alpha)-40$$

$$P=150\alpha + 50\pi - 200$$

However it's impossible to calculate $\alpha$ without trigonometry:

$$\tan \alpha = \frac86 = \frac43\implies \alpha \approx 0.927 \space\text{rad}, \space\space P\approx 96.174$$

If you want something really tricky try to find area of the red shape in the middle:

[image]

Comment: which tool do you use to draw first figure ? I see that it is an image posted on Imgur, but I'm interesting to know the tool that you are using.

Comment: @schlebe: GeoGebra, as a plugin for Chrome. If you liked the solution, consider upvoting it.

Comment: it is done :-) but I'm not sure that no solution exists !

Comment: @schlebe The solution exists, it's just impossible to replace $\tan^{-1}\frac43$ with anything simpler.

Comment: Perhaps the assumption is that because $EJF$ is a triangle with sides 3:4:5 (twice that, actually), the angle $\alpha$ is [known](https://www.mathopenref.com/triangle345.html), 36.87°?

Comment: 36,87° ? why not arccos(3/5) = 0,927 radian = 53,13° ! I think that 36,87° is $\pi/2 - \alpha$

Answer (score 0):

Lets denote area as A; we have following areas:

$A_1 =20^2 -\frac{1}{4}. 20^2. \pi$

Big Ellipse like area: $A_2=\frac{1}{4}. 20^2.\pi-(20^2 -\frac{1}{4}. 20^2. \pi)=228$

$A_3=\frac{1}{4}. 10^2.\pi-\frac{1}{2}. 10^2=28.5; 2 A_3=57=\frac{1}{4} A_2$

Where $2 A_2$ is small ellipse like area inside the big one.

Required area $A_4$ is:

$A_4≈ 228(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{16}- \frac{1}{48})≈97$
[image]